# Page jumps while scrolling page vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been encountering a problem from sometime now.Looked up with similar problems on stackoverflow.But none could help me.

Problem is that my html page is jumping, when i scroll it.
If the content is less than the total height of the page, it doesnt jump, but as the content go little bigger than the total height of the page it starts jumping

What are the possible solution, if anyone could help me a bit.
Thanks in advance.I am using bootstrap.

**html**

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/welcome">
                    <img src="/resources/images/senabLogo.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- navbar-header -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/welcome">Home</a>
                    </li>



                            <li><a href="/offers">Offers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/settings">Settings</a></li>

                            <li class="dropdown menu-item">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Language</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="?language=en">EN</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="?language=sv">SV</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="?language=no">NO</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>


                </ul>
                <!-- nav navbar-nav -->
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
                    <ul class="LoginDetailsH">

                            <li>Sales</li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:formSubmit()">Log out <span class="fa fa-sign-out">&nbsp;</span></a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown menu-item pull-right">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-question-circle">&nbsp;</span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="https://intranet.senab.com/diskussioner/categories/listings/fsvb" target="_blank">View open and closed questions</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://intranet.senab.com/diskussioner/ask/sales-to-cash/fsvb" target="_blank">Ask a new question</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                    </ul>
                    <!-- LoginDetailsH -->
                </div>
                <!-- col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right -->
            </div>
            <!-- collapse navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

<div class="container">

</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-fixed-top {position:relative !important;}
```

I have referrd to the foloowing

[Prevent page from jumping while changing position of element on scroll function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480429/prevent-page-from-jumping-while-changing-position-of-element-on-scroll-function)

[How do I stop a web page from scrolling to the top when a link is clicked that triggers JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601933/how-do-i-stop-a-web-page-from-scrolling-to-the-top-when-a-link-is-clicked-that-t)

Comment: Your html only has a nav bar? or show a demo snippet.

Comment: well voting down wont help, if you all are so perfect then try answering it.

Comment: no there is a container also, and in that container I am keeping lot of stuff there

Comment: what do you mean by - it jumps? Is it so that the normal scrolling is jumpy? Is it a normal website or it has effects on scrolling?

Comment: its a normal website with normal scrolling, with less content, when scrolled, page starts jumping up and down.